# How to generate just the URL of the Controller method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, html.actionlink

So `Html.ActionLink("Report", "SendMail", "Misc", new { id = Model.ImageID }, null)` will generate a nicely formatted link.

```
<a href="http://localhost:3224/Misc/SendMail/5">Send Mail</a>
```

How can I generate just the URL of the link, short of parsing the output of Html.ActionLink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you

```
<%= Url.Content("~/Misc/SendMail/" + Model.ImageID) %>
```

Or try

```
<%= Url.Action( "SendMail", "Misc", new { id = Model.ImageID }) %>
```

Comment: This is good, but the app will run on various IIS boxes (some v6 and some v7), so it could potentially be /Misc.aspx/SendMail, in the case of IIS6.

Comment: Url.Action might be your friend.

Comment: Yep, thank you.  This generates /Misc.aspx/SendMail/1, which is perfect.  Now I need the stuff that comes before it.  Any idea how to get the domain + virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Url.Content("~"+Url.Action( "SendMail", "Misc", new { id = Model.ImageID })) %>
```

should work for you i think